# POM is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I want to clean and build my project, but facing issues with BUILD FAILURE.
The error message that I got is **The POM for com.paymaster:paymaster:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available**. Is there any solution to this?
Thank you.

Comment: Dependencies you add to your pom.xml should be available: 
1- In default mvnrepository.org 
2- The repository details for custom repositories must be provided
3- Located in [user home directory]/.m2

Comment: @SaeedAlizadeh Something like `mvnrepository.org` as a default does not exist. In Maven the central repository is the default...